# T-SQL - Return records with same values in two columns, but different value in third column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by, count

Given this sample data:

```
ID    lname        fname    num
1     Jones        Mary     672
2     Jones        Mary     123
3     Johnson      Ellen    853
4     Jones        Mary     123
5     Jones        Scott    342
6     Smith        John     874
7     Anders       David    433
8     Northson     Sue      756
9     Fredricks    George   555
10    Northson     Sue      756
11    Northson     Sue      756
12    Perry        Nicole   335
11    Northson     Sue      342
```

I want to find all lname/fname pairs that have multiple "num"s and the count of rows with that "num" value.

So the result set should look like this:

```
lname        fname    num    count
Jones        Mary     672    1
Jones        Mary     123    2
Northson     Sue      756    3
Northson     Sue      342    1
```

The only thing that I could come up with is the below, but the select in the where clause returns more than row

```
select
    lname
    ,fname
    ,num
    ,COUNT(*)
from sampleTable
where
    (num != (select x.num
             from sampleTable x
             where x.ID != sampleTable.ID
                 and x.fname = sampleTable.fname
                 and x.lname = sampleTable.lname)   
     )
group by lname, fname, num
--having count(num) > 1
order by lname, fname, num
```

Comment: if you remove the where clause, what results do you get?

Comment: @Jeremy, That doesn't filter out the records where there is only one num value for a given lname/fname combination. (essentially it just adds a "count" column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to join on another query and count the number of distinct `num`s per `lname`/`fname` combination:

```
SELECT   a.lname, a.fname, a.num, a.cnt
FROM     (SELECT   lname, fname, num, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     sampleatable
          GROUP BY lname, fname, num) a
JOIN     (SELECT   lname, fname
          FROM     sampletable
          GROUP BY lname, fname
          HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT num) > 1) b ON a.lname = b.lname AND a.fname = b.fname
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mureinik. That gave me exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
select  lname, fname, num, 
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY lname, fname, num ORDER BY lname, fname, num) as cnt,
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY lname, fname ORDER BY lname, fname) as pairs
from  sampleTable
```

returns (from my temp version of your table)

```
lname   fname   num cnt pairs
Jones   Mary    123 1   1
Jones   Mary    672 1   2
Jones   Scott   111 1   1
Jones   Scott   111 2   2
Jones   Scott   342 1   3
Jones   Scott   874 1   4
```